# Conditional if in struts2 tags

Tags: java, struts2, jsp-tags

I have the following code.

```
<s:push value="#session['person']">
         <s:if test="%{admin=='y'}">
            <a class="add" href="/projit1/project/addProject.jsp">Create a Project</a>
        </s:if>
        </s:push>
```

I am trying push an object person from session map to valuestack and check one of its properties admin's value. If it is 'y' then the link "create a project" appears.

But this code is not working. If i use the above code, both admins and normal members does not see the link. what could be the problem ? please help

Comment: Just confirm on these, you must have a proper setter method in your `Person` class for `admin` attribute. If thats perfectly fine, why not try the condition directly without push it into value stack?

Comment: yes, i have checked it. admin is perfectly set .

Comment: and you're surely setting admin with lower case y ?

Comment: yes i have set it up with lower case y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
    <s:push value="person">
      <s:if test="%{admin=='y'}">
        <a class="add" href="/projit1/project/addProject.jsp">Create a Project</a>
      </s:if>
    </s:push>
```

Comment: i have the person object set in session map

Comment: Session context is available here. Just like JSTL it would look for this attribute in page, then request, then session and then application. So, in your case the attribute should be found in session state.

Answer (score 0):

And you have a `getAdmin()` or `isAdmin()` on your Person object I assume?  If that's the case, I also assume the method returns a `char` 'y'?   I suggest you try displaying the result of calling admin and go from there.  e.g.

```
<s:push value="#session['person']">
  admin: <s:property value="%{admin}" />
  <s:if test="%{admin=='y'}">
    <a class="add" href="/projit1/project/addProject.jsp">Create a Project</a>
  </s:if>
</s:push>
```